# Loop through list with both content and index

Tags: python, list, loops

It is very common for me to loop through a python list to get both the contents *and* their indexes. What I usually do is the following:

```
S = [1,30,20,30,2] # My list
for s, i in zip(S, range(len(S))):
    # Do stuff with the content s and the index i
```

I find this syntax a bit ugly, especially the part inside the `zip` function. Are there any more elegant/Pythonic ways of doing this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use the `enumerate` built-in function: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 198):

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> S = [1,30,20,30,2]
>>> for index, elem in enumerate(S):
        print(index, elem)

(0, 1)
(1, 30)
(2, 20)
(3, 30)
(4, 2)
```

Comment: This is the answer. Just providing the link like in the selected answer is not "StackOverflow-esc"

Comment: I am sending data using ajax to Django views as an array in the form of two values in a variable **legData** with values as `[1406, 1409]`. If I print to the console using `print(legData)` I get the output as **[1406,1409]**. However, if I try to parse the individual values of the list like `for idx, xLeg in enumerate(legData):` `print(idx, xLeg)`, I am getting an output of individual **integers** such as [, 1, 4, 0, 6 and so on against the indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. (**yes, the square brackets & comma are also being output as if they were part of the data itself**). What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 29):

Like everyone else:

```
for i, val in enumerate(data):
    print i, val
```

but ***also***

```
for i, val in enumerate(data, 1):
    print i, val
```

In other words, you can specify as ***starting value*** for the index/count generated by [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) which comes in handy if you don't want your index to start with the *default value of zero*.

I was printing out lines in a file the other day and specified the starting value as 1 for `enumerate()`, which made more sense than 0 when displaying information about a specific line to the user.

Answer (score 6):

`enumerate` is what you want:

```
for i, s in enumerate(S):
    print s, i
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> for i, s in enumerate(S):
```

Answer (score 4):

`enumerate()` makes this prettier:

```
for index, value in enumerate(S):
    print index, value
```

See [here](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/) for more.