# Way to pass multiple parameters in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

My code:

```py
seperated = startContent.split(' ')
seperatedNum = len(seperated)

#Ask for user input

for word in seperated and for i in seperatedNum:
    if word == 'ADJECTIVE':
        seperated[i] = input('Enter an adjective:')
    elif word == 'NOUN':
        seperated[i] = input('Enter a noun:')
    elif word == 'ADVERB':
        seperated[i] = input('Enter an adverb:')
    elif word == 'VERB':
        seperated[i] = input('Enter a verb:')
```

Basically asking the user input each time they run into one of the following words (there can be multiple of each).

I get my sentence, split it into a list with split command. And run the loop for each word. I want to then edit the list using `list[x] = 'replacement'` method.

The word in `seperated`, returns the listitem. So I need another argument passed to it, e.g `i in len(list)` to then get the accurate index of the word. I can't use `list.index(str)` because it returns the first index of the string when there are multiple iterations of the text.

Comment: In this case, you are looking for `enumerate`.

Comment: New to python, what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, should have provided more info. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean

Comment: That is so helpful! Thank you so much, knew what I wanted made sense but needed to know how to do it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through list with both content and index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475748/loop-through-list-with-both-content-and-index)

Comment: Use the `enumerate` function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a way to pass multiple parameters in a `for` loop: There is nothing special about a `for` loop in this regard. The loop will iterate over a given sequence and will, each iteration, assign the current element to the given left-hand side.

```py
for LEFT_HAND_SIDE in SEQUENCE
```

Python also supports "automatic" unpacking of sequences during assigments, as you can see in the following example:

```
>>> a, b = (4, 2)
>>> a
4
>>> b
2
```

In conclusion, you can just combine multiple variables on the left-hand side in your `for` loop with a sequence of sequences:

```
>>> for a, b in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]:
...     print(a)
...     print(b)
... 
1
2
3
4
```

That `for` loop had two assignments `a, b = (1, 2)` and `a, b = (3, 4)`.

In you specific case, you want to combine the value of an element in a sequence with its index. The built-in function [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) comes in handy here:

```
>>> enumerate(["x", "y"])
<enumerate object at 0x7fc72f6685a0>
>>> list(enumerate(["x", "y"]))
[(0, 'x'), (1, 'y')]
```

So you could write your `for` loop like this:

```py
for i, word in enumerate(seperated)
```