# How do I add an item number to each number in the list?

Tags: python

Add an index number to each element of the array in it
for example
I need to output it like this test. 7; 3; 0; -5; 1; 2; 8; 4. The result. 7; 4; 2; -2; 5; 7; 14; 11.

```
import random
rand_mass = []
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    rand_mass.append(random.randint(-5, 9))
```

and what should I do next?

Comment: Just add i+1 to each random value but I'm not sure what this really achieves

Comment: for some reason in your test case the indexing starts with 1 which is incorrect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through list with both content and index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475748/loop-through-list-with-both-content-and-index)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/522563/4046632

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
import random

n = 10

# if your index starts at 0

rand_initial = [random.randint(-5, 9)   for i in range(n)]
rand_mass    = [rand_initial[idx] + idx for idx in range(n)]

print(rand_initial)
print(rand_mass)
```

Comment: i`am new in python and can you give me full cod please?

Comment: that is the full code

Comment: after execution, it does not add the index number

Comment: yes it does, do you also want the list of random numbers without the added index?

Comment: with addeded index numbers

Comment: I have amended the code to give both the initial random numbers & the same list with an index added

Answer (score -1):

You can add the `i` index to each value that you append to the list +1, since `i` starts at `0`.

```
import random
rand_mass = []
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    rand_mass.append( random.randint(-5, 9) + (i+1) )
```